# Spin a instance in VPC from a AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, vpc

I have the following code which basically creates a AMI of a instance.. i need to launch a same instance from this AMI in exact same region, subnet, VPC etc.. i.e same copy of original instance.

```
import boto.ec2
import time
import sys 
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")

reservations=conn.get_all_instances(sys.argv[1])
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
#    print(i.__dict__)
    print "The",i,"has the following attributes:"
    a = i.image_id
    b = i.vpc_id
    c = i.key_name
    d = i.region
    e = i.subnet_id
#print a
#print "========"

ami_id = conn.create_image(sys.argv[1], "nitis", description="Testing", no_reboot=True, block_device_mapping=None, dry_run=False)
##image = conn.get_all_images(image_ids=[image_id])[0]

print "The new AMI is being created with id -->  %s" %ami_id

image = conn.get_image(ami_id)
while image.state == 'pending':
    time.sleep(10)
    image = conn.get_image(ami_id)
    #image.update()
    print "AMI still pending.. waiting 10 more sec!!! state:%s" % (image.state) 

if image.state == 'available':
   print "AMI CREATED SUCCESSFULLY with AMI id = %s" % ami_id   
else:
   print "Something Went Wrong!!" 
########################################Replication CODE################################
reservations = conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=[sys.argv[1]])
instances = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
for i in instances:
    key_name = i.key_name
    security_group = i.groups
    instance_type = i.instance_type
    subnet_name = i.subnet_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,subnet_id=subnet_name ,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)
    print "new replica system id is " + reserve.instances[0].id
```

Actually the code before the REPLICATION CODE works fine and created a AMI .. after that i need to launch the instance, which throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_AMI_n_spin_instance.py", line 43, in <module>
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,subnet_id=subnet_name ,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 973, in run_instances
    verb='POST')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1208, in get_object
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterCombination</Code><Message>The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>5242ae3a-03ea-491c-a230-5d86afcc3870</RequestID></Response>
```

Comment: Use without subnet id      reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)

Comment: how does it knows abt the VPC in which it needs to be launched ??

Comment: boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidGroup.NotFound</Code><Message>The security group '&lt;boto.ec2.group.group object at 0x7f6970aafc10&gt;' does not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>91f31d27-b656-4efa-9dd4-a9ccdadac828</RequestID></Response>

Comment: My bad, you are right, its just that your code is probably not getting the right security group, can you print the security_group and check if its right

Comment: yes.. its not getting the right sec group ,
i printed the sec group .. it has the value: [<boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0x7f86b0f74a90>]

Comment: I think its returning an array of groups, can you print security_group[0]

Comment: it prints same stuff <boto.ec2.group.Group object at 0x7f1023d58a90>

Comment: that's a bummer, why don't we first try the "hardcoded" security group, this hex address thing looks intimidating, but may be we just don't know how to parse this, lets see how we can

Comment: okay.. trying that..

Comment: boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidParameterCombination</Code><Message>VPC security groups may not be used for a non-VPC launch</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>57c29a87-8f6c-462d-a16b-7a4888dd5341</RequestID></Response>

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the name of a security group in a VPC, you have to use the ID of the group.  I think something like this should work for you.

```
for i in instances:
    key_name = i.key_name
    security_group = [g.id for g in i.groups]
    instance_type = i.instance_type
    subnet_name = i.subnet_id
    reserve = conn.run_instances(image_id=ami_id,key_name=key_name,subnet_id=subnet_name ,instance_type=instance_type,security_group_ids =security_group)
    print "new replica system id is " + reserve.instances[0].id
```